# Prove that $x/9 + (\sin x)/8=\cos^2(x/3)+\cos^2x+1$ has a positive solution.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, roots

I'm trying to solve this problem but after several attempts I wasn't able to prove it. I know there is a point where the intermediate value theorem should be used (that's the topic of the unit) but I find quite hard to found at least analytically the extremes of the interval so I can use it.

Prove that $x/9 + (\sin x)/8=\cos^2(x/3)+\cos^2x+1$ has a positive solution.

Comment: Remember to make sure your question is completely contained in the question body- don’t leave important details to be only mentioned in the title. Many devices (like the one I’m currently on) don’t render mathjax in the title.

Comment: thank you, I'll edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let$$f(x)=\frac x9+\frac{\sin x}8-\cos^2\left(\frac x3\right)-\cos^2(x)-1.$$Then, since $f$ is continuous and since $f(0)=-3$ and $f(9\pi)=\pi-3>0$, there is some $c\in(0,9\pi)$ such that $f(c)=0$. So,$$\frac c9+\frac{\sin c}8=\cos^2\left(\frac c3\right)+\cos^2(c)+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

At $x = 0$, the left-hand side (LHS) of the equation equals zero, while the right-hand side (RHS) equals three, i.e., LHS < RHS.

However, at some very large $x$, say $100000$, obviously LHS > RHS. Thus, somewhere in between, LHS = RHS.